# How can I give the user choice again in the following small c++ code?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void playgame ()
{}

void loadgame ()
{}

void playmultiplayer ()
{}

int main ()
{
    int input;

    cout << "1. Play game\n";
    cout << "2. Load game\n";
    cout << "3. Play multiplayer\n";
    cout << "4. Exit\n";
    cout << "Selection: ";
    cin >> input;
    switch ( input ) 
    {
    case 1:            // Note the colon after each case, not a semicolon
        playgame();
        break;
    case 2:
        loadgame();
        break;
    case 3: 
        playmultiplayer();
        break;
    case 4: 
        cout << "Thank you for playing!\n";
        break;
    default:            // Note the colon for default, not a semicolon
        cout << "Error, bad input, quitting\n";
        break;
    }
}
```

This code is from the book I am currently studying, "jumping into c++" to describle the working of switch. 
the author said " one issue you might notice is that the user gets only a single choice before the program exists. We can use while loop to around the switch block to solve the issue". 
my question is - How can we use while loop to solve the issue? I tried a lot but am unable to do it. 
Thanks.

Comment: What went wrong when you tried putting "while ([some condition]){" and "}" around the the code?

Comment: Well, what did you try?  For a while loop to work, you'll need to identify which part needs to be looped, and have a variable to check in order to terminate the loop.

Comment: @doctorlove I need the condition such that the loop is repeated only when we press something other than 1,2 3 or 4. I put 2 break but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Stick with `break` in switch statements and don't use them inside for loops, or while loops - it's often easier to reason about the code if you avoid making it jump around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this using a `do { ... } while()` loop construct.

```
do {
  if(cin >> input) {
    // your switch
    switch(input) {
      case 1:
        break; //
      // so on
      case 4:
        cout << "Thank You!" << std::endl;
        break;
    }
  } else {
    // io error
    break;
  }
} while (input != 4);
```

I'd like to point out that your book probably sucks. Reading from a stream without checking the return value is just plain bad code. My code checks if the formatted input function actually extract output.

Comment: "Reading from a stream without checking the return value is just plain bad code"... can you please elaborate?

Comment: In your case `int input;` is not initialized and has an unspecified value. If `cin >> input` fails (which it will for every input that is not convertible to int), you will access this unspecified value in your switch, which is undefined behavior. If it happens in the loop, the int is going to retain its previous value and the same action is executed twice.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the code in a do while loop and instead of exiting in the case 4,u can have the exit condition defined in the while condition.This way the user gets the option until he chooses 4

Answer (score 0):

I guess the book will show examples of loops in the next chapter or so.

To answer your question: (as endless loop)

```
while(true)
{
   //your code starting with cout ... ending with the closing } othe switch
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void playgame ()
{}

void loadgame ()
{}

void playmultiplayer ()
{}

int main ()
{
    int input;

    while(1)
    {
       cout << "1. Play game\n";
       cout << "2. Load game\n";
       cout << "3. Play multiplayer\n";
       cout << "4. Exit\n";
       cout << "Selection: ";
       cin >> input;
       switch ( input ) 
       {
       case 1:            // Note the colon after each case, not a semicolon
        playgame();
        break;
       case 2:
        loadgame();
        break;
       case 3: 
        playmultiplayer();
        break;
       case 4: 
        cout << "Thank you for playing!\n";
        exit(1);
        break;
       default:            // Note the colon for default, not a semicolon
        cout << "Error, bad input, quitting\n";
        break;
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap everything inside `main()` inside the following:

```
bool quit = false;

while(!quit)
{
    //your code

}
```

And for cases 4 and 5, add

```
quit = true;
```

before `break;`